# how to install Fedora 20 on usb? (.iso)

Tags: fedora20

I want install `Fedora 20` iso file on usb.

`https://getfedora.org/` this site. only support fedora 24.

how to install fedora 20 iso file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer a part of your question. The fedora project archieve is [here](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/), you can find your desired version of iso.

Some useful tools to make Linux live USB:

- [LiveUSB Creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/)
- [Universal USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com)
- [Using dd command](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media)

Comment: yes , I want create boot image on usb

Comment: I've edited for more.

Comment: thanks! I check your advice

Comment: @chohyunwook It looks like Fedora 20 lifetime was ended https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system). So consider to use latest for more supports. There aren't much changes between releases.